# pyplot.hist2d ValueError 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am learning how to use various plotting functions in Python and when I tried creating a 2D histogram using `numpy.pyplot.hist2d`, I get a "ValueError 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)" message. Here is the full code I am using:

```py
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import seed 
from numpy.random import rand 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pit 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

X = [] 
y = []

X.append(rand(l)*l00)
Y.append(rand(1)*100)

for i in range(l,10000):
    X.append(rand(1)*100) 
    Y.append(X[i-1])

mu = np.mean(X) 
sigma = np.std(X) 

fig = pit.figure() 
axes = fig.subplots() 
axes.scatter(X, Y, s=.5) 
pit.show() 
print("X mean = {}\nX std dev = {}".format(mu, sigma)) x = np.array(X) 
 
plt.hist2d(X,Y, bins='auto') 
pit.show()
```

[image: Scatterplot Output]

X mean = 50.271585907067916
X std dev = 28.926289139289707

I tried using `axes.hist2d(X,Y, bins='auto')` instead of `plt.hist2d(X,Y, bins='auto')`, but get the same error. Here is the full traceback report:

---

```py
<p>AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) </p>
<p>/usr/share/jupyter/venvs/cognos-5.12.4/lib/python3.7 /site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py in histogramdd(sample, bins, range, normed, weights, density) </p>
<p>
 1015   # Sample is an ND-array.<br>
 1016   N, D = sample.shape <br>
 1017   except (AttributeError, ValueError): </p>

<p>AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' </p>
<p> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:</p>
 
<p> ValueError      Traceback (most recent call last) </p>
<p> /tmp/ipykernel_ 452/1275939754.py in 
<module> </p>
<p> 
---> 36    plt.hist2d(X,Y, bins='auto') <br>
 37    plt.show()</p> 
 
<p> /usr/share/jupyter/venvs/cognos-5.12.4/lib/python3.7 /site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in hist2d(x, y, bins, range, density, weights, cmin, cmax, data, **kwargs) </p>
<p>
2625    x, y, bins=bins, range=range, density=density, <br>
2626    weights=weights, cmin=cmin,cmax=cmax, <br>
---> 2627   **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs) <br>
2628    sci(_ret[-1]) <br>
2629    return _ret </p>
 
<p> /usr/share/jupyter/venvs/cognos-5.12.4/lib/python3.7 /site-packages/matplotlib/ _init_.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs) </p>
<p>
1412    def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs): <br>
1413    if data is None: <br>
---> 1414    return func(ax,*map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs) <br>
1415<br>
1416    bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs) </p>
 
<p> /usr/share/jupyter/venvs/cognos-5.12.4/lib/python3.7 /site-packages/matplotlib/axes/ _axes.py in hist2d(self, x, y, bins, range, density, weights, cmin, cmax, **kwargs) </p>
<p>
6981<br>
6982    h, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, range=range, <br>
---> 6983        density=density, weights=weights) <br>
6984<br>
6985    if cmin is not None: </p>
 
<p><_array_function_ internals> in histogram2d(*args, **kwargs) </p>
 
<p> /usr/share/jupyter/venvs/cognos-5.12.4/lib/python3.7 /site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py in histogram2d(x, y, bins, range, normed, weights, density) </p>
<p>
749    xedges = yedges = asarray(bins) <br>
750    ins = [xedges, yedges] <br>
---> 751    hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights, density) <br>
752    return hist, edges[O], edges[l] </p>
<p> 
<_array_function_ internals> in histogramdd(*args, **kwargs) </p>
 
<p> /usr/share/jupyter/venvs/cognos-5.12.4/lib/python3.7 /site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py in histogramdd(sample, bins, range, normed, weights, density) </p>
<p> 
1018    # Sample is a sequence of 1D arr<br>ays. 
1019    sample = np.atleast_2d(sample).T <br>
---> 1020    N, D = sample.shape <br>
1021<br>
1022    nbin = np.empty(D, int) </p>
 
<p>Value Error: too many values to unpack (expected 2) </p>
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `axes = fig.subplot()` (without the `s`) instead of `axes = fig.subplots()`? Normally you should get an error with `axes.scatter(X, Y, s=.5)`, because `axes` has the wrong type at that point. Also the rest of your code looks quite strange:  you are mixing the letter `l` with the number `1`. And `y` and with `Y`, while `Y` doesn't get initialized.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` the standard alias is `plt`, not `pit`. You're even confused by the non-standard alias, as you specified `plt.hist2d(X,Y, bins='auto')`. Stick with standard aliases to avoid confusion (for everyone).

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code, including undefined variables, which make this an incomplete [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code has a lot of typos. First, let's solve this problem.

```
pit -> plt
X.append(rand(l)*l00) -> X.append(rand(1)*l00) # l -> 1
for i in range(l,10000): -> for i in range(1,10000): # l -> 1
```

Then, following the code is solved to your problem.

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import seed 
from numpy.random import rand 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

X = [] 
Y = []

X.append(rand(1)*100)
Y.append(rand(1)*100)

for i in range(1,10000):
    X.append(rand(1)*100) 
    Y.append(X[i-1])

mu = np.mean(X) 
sigma = np.std(X) 

fig = plt.figure() 
axes = fig.subplots() 
axes.scatter(X, Y, s=.5) 
plt.show() 


print("X mean = {}\nX std dev = {}".format(mu, sigma)) 

x = np.array(X) 
y = np.array(Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.hist2d(x[:,0],y[:,0], bins=10) 
fig.colorbar(h[3], ax=ax)
```

I added `colorbar` to view the result more intuitively.

As see the last line, you can see the change `[:,0]` and `bins=10`, which are making the errors that you raise. I don't know where you find the option, but there is no the option `auto` in official [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html).

 
Besides, the slicing `[:,0]` allows you to reduce the original dimension of the X and Y.

```
print(x.shape)
print(x[:,0].shape)
(10000, 1)
(10000,)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your corrections worked! The typos you noticed only existed in the code block I posted here because I wasn't able to directly copy the original code for pasting into another app. I was forced to save the code as a PDF file and then run it through text recognition, which wasn't too reliable.

Comment: I also mixed up the bins = 'auto'  selection from the numpy.histogram function parameters with the bins parameter in the matplotlib.pyplot library histogram functions. My apologies.

Comment: @Kevin good to sound it's done well. It's ok, everyone makes their mistake. Have a good day.